# Receiving events from VS service in VSIX extension right from IDE startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix, vsx, visual-studio-package

I am trying to create a Visual Studio Extension that closes the least recently used documents. In order to achieve this I need to be able to track when a document has been last used. The way I am doing this is registering a RDT table listener (AdviseRunningDocTableEvents) in the Package::Initialize method. However, this only gets executed when I first run the 'cleanup' command.

Is there a way to register a listener for the RDT table that would be receiving events right from the VS startup? Bearing in mind that I need to access VS services, where would the proper place for such code be?

Comment: Are you looking for the ProvideAutoLoad attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/loading-vspackages ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much - I don't know how I could've missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A package can be set to [autoload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/loading-vspackages) in a particular user interface context, for example, when a solution is open.

The [ProvideAutoLoadAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.provideautoloadattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) attribute sets this context.

```
....
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)] // choose when you want it to be loaded
...
public class MyAutoloadedPackage : Package  
{
    ...
}
```